# Scanning data from text file, that doesn't have spacing between each item of data

Tags: c, text, scanf

I have encountered a problem with my homework. I need to scan some data from a text file, to a struct. 
The text file looks like this.

```
012345678;danny;cohen;22;M;danny1993;123;1,2,4,8;Nice person
223325222;or;dan;25;M;ordan10;1234;3,5,6,7;Singer and dancer
203484758;shani;israel;25;F;shaninush;12345;4,5,6,7;Happy and cool girl
349950234;nadav;cohen;50;M;nd50;nadav;3,6,7,8;Engineer very smart
345656974;oshrit;hasson;30;F;osh321;111;3,4,5,7;Layer and a painter
```

Each item of data to its matching variable.
id = 012345678
first_name = danny
etc...

Now I can't use fscanf because there is no spacing, and the fgets scanning all the line.

I found some solution with %[^;]s, but then I will need to write one block of code and, copy and past it 9 times for each item of data.

Is there any other option without changing the text file, that similar to the code I would write with fscanf, if there was spacing between each item of data?

************* UPDATE **************

Hey, First of all, thanks everyone for the help really appreciating.
I didn't understand all your answers, but here something I did use.

Here's my code :

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *idP, *firstNameP, *lastNameP;
    int age;
    char gender, *userNameP, *passwordP, hobbies, *descriptionP;
}user;


void main() {
    FILE *fileP;
    user temp;
    char test[99];

    temp.idP = (char *)malloc(99);
    temp.firstNameP = (char *)malloc(99);
    temp.lastNameP = (char *)malloc(99);
    temp.age = (int )malloc(4);
    temp.gender = (char )malloc(sizeof(char));
    temp.userNameP = (char *)malloc(99);

    fileP = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fileP, "%9[^;];%99[^;];%99[^;];%d;%c", temp.idP,temp.firstNameP,temp.lastNameP,&temp.age, temp.gender);
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n%c", temp.idP, temp.firstNameP, temp.lastNameP, temp.age, temp.gender);

    fgets(test, 60, fileP); // Just testing where it stop scanning
    printf("\n\n%s", test);

    fclose(fileP);
    getchar();
}
```

It all works well until I scan the int variable, right after that it doesn't scan anything, and I get an error.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The general case: build a DFA. Skipping (optional) whitespace is only an extra state (or maybe two)

Comment: In particular, note that `%[^;]` is the complete specifier, and _not_ followed by an `s`.

Comment: What is the problem with the fscanf specifier (with corrections mentioned in comments)? It shouldn't be significantly longer than the usual methods for whitespace-separated strings and if the code block was to be repeated multiple times, you would write a loop and/or function for it.

Comment: @xing Yes I tried it, but then I will need to do it 9 times. Like copy past the same code with the changes of the variables.

Comment: OT: "_Layer_ and a painter"?

Comment: Read the whole line and use strtok to tokenize it.

Comment: @Jen What do you mean copypaste? `fscanf(file, " %9[^;];%99[^;];…;%99[^\n]", &s.f1, &s.f2, …, &s.f9)`. You can't get any shorter, really, since you need to mention each destination field and its format at least once. It's certainly shorter than `strtok` where you probably need two function calls per field. (But overall, nothing wrong with that solution either.)

Comment: @Arkku Oh yes, I tried what you wrote, but like this %9[^;] without the semicolon between, now it works. Why do you need to put the semicolon?

Comment: I think he has more than one delimiter here

Comment: "Now I can't use fscanf because there is no spacing" is an incorrect conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, `fscanf` is probably the shortest option (although `fgets` followed by `strtok`, and manual parsing are viable options).

You need to use the `%[^;]` specifier for the string fields (meaning: a string of characters *other than* `;`), with the fields separated by `;` to consume the actual semicolons (which we specifically requested not to be consumed as part of the string field). The last field should be `%[^\n]` to consume up to the newline, since the input doesn't have a terminating semicolon.

You should also (always) limit the length of each string field read with a `scanf` family function to one less than the available space (the terminating NUL byte is the +1). So, for example, if the first field is at most 9 characters long, you would need `char field1[10]` and the format would be `%9[^;]`.

It is usually a good idea to put a single space in the beginning of the format string to consume any whitespace (such as the previous newline).

And, of course you should check the return value of `fscanf`, e.g., if you have 9 fields as per the example, it should return `9`.

So, the end result would be something like:

```
if (fscanf(file, " %9[^;];%99[^;];%99[^;];%d;%c;%99[^;];%d;%99[^;];%99[^\n]",
           s.field1, s.field2, s.field3, &s.field4, …, s.field9) != 9) {
    // error
    break;
}
```

(Alternatively, the field with numbers separated by commas could be read as four separate fields as `%d,%d,%d,%d`, in which case the count would go up to 12.)

Comment: Likely `s.field1` is needed than `&s.field1` as supposedly `.field1` is an array.  For clarity, suggest adding a sample `struct` for `s`.

Comment: @chux Thanks, my bad about the extra `&`. As for the sample `struct`, I don't think it's particularly enlightening for me to make up lengths and types without knowing the OPs intent, so omitting it unless needed by OP.

Comment: @Arkku Hey, I tried it, works well till the %d, after that, I get an error. I updated the post... Thanks

Comment: @Jen You need to pass a pointer, so the age field needs & to take its address. And you don’t need to allocate it separately, it is already included in the struct.

Comment: @Arkku Ya I have the &, &temp.age, still get the error. I deleted the allocation for the int.

Comment: @Jen Please enable (and read) the warnings on your compiler, it should warn about incorrect type. In order to store the results, `fscanf` needs pointers to the type being converted, i.e., for `%d` you need `int *` and for `%c` you need `char *`. So, since you have `char gender`, you need to pass `&gender` to `fscanf`, since the `&` "adds a `*` to the type" by taking the address. (The strings are already `char *` in your struct, so they don't need the additional `&`.)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have simple tokenizer. As I see you have more than one delimiter here (`;` & `,`)

`str` - string to be tokenized

`del` - string containing delimiters (in your case `";,"` or `";"` only)

`allowempty` - if true allows empty tokens if there are two or more consecutive delimiters

return value is a NULL terminated table of pointers to the tokens.

```
char **mystrtok(const char *str, const char *del, int allowempty)
{
  char **result = NULL;
  const char *end = str;
  size_t size = 0;
  int extrachar;

  while(*end)
  {
    if((extrachar = !!strchr(del, *end)) || !*(end + 1))
    {
        /* add temp variable and malloc / realloc checks */
        /* free allocated memory on error */
        if(!(!allowempty && !(end - str)))
        {
            extrachar = !extrachar * !*(end + 1);
            result = realloc(result, (++size + 1) * sizeof(*result));
            result[size] = NULL;
            result[size -1] = malloc(end - str + 1 + extrachar);
            strncpy(result[size -1], str, end - str + extrachar);
            result[size -1][end - str + extrachar] = 0;
        }
        str = end + 1;
    }
    end++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

To free the the memory allocated by the tokenizer:

```
void myfree(char **ptr)
{
    char **savedptr = ptr;
    while(*ptr)
    {
        free(*ptr++);
    }
    free(savedptr);
}
```

Function is simple but your can use any separators and any number of separators.