# VS goes nuts after second realloc

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

So I have an input file, which has the following text (each line = user):

```
012345678;danny;cohen;22;M;danny1993;123;1,2,4,8;Nice person
223325222;or;dan;25;M;ordan10;1234;3,5,6,7;Singer and dancer
349950234;nadav;cohen;50;M;nd50;nadav;3,6,7,8;Engineer very smart
```

at first the code allocates room for one user, and then it reallocates room for 1 more (for each user). the thing is, that everything goes great till the second time reallocating, then it shows me the error "Exercise 6.exe has triggered a breakpoint." I will also mention the error was at first:
"“wntdll.pdb not loaded” but I tried doing what the VS suggeset- something with symbols. Then came "triggered a breakpoint" error.

I tried switching the rows in the text file, but it didn't matter, the problem occurs after trying reallocating for the second time.

let me show you the relevant part of the code:

```
int main()
{
    //intiallizing variables
    int menArraySize = 0;
    //creating a NULL array pointer (array) for men
    User *head = NULL;
    readInputFile(head, &menArraySize, list);
}

void readInputFile(User *head, int *menArraySize, WomenList *list)
{
    //temporary data types for the the stracture we're creating
    char id[10];
    char *firstName = NULL;
    char *lastName = NULL;
    char age[4] = { 0 };
    char gender = '\0';
    char *userName = NULL;
    char *password = NULL;
    char hobbies = 0;
    char *description = NULL;
    //regular function data types
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, currentDetail = 1, size;
    char currentString[212] = { 0 };
    int currentChar;

    //opening the input file
    FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
...
//long code for allocating room for each string (firstName, lastName, etc...)- irelevant
...
    head = addMale(head, menArraySize, id, firstName, lastName, age,
        gender, userName, password, hobbies, description);
...
//rest of the function isn't relevant
}

User* addMale(User *head ,int *menArraySize, char id[], char *firstName, 
char *lastName,char age[], char gender, char *userName,


char *password, char hobbies, char *description)
            {
                //if the array is empty, allocate room for one user
                if (*menArraySize == 0)
                {
                    head = (User *)malloc(1 * sizeof(User));
                }
                //if the array isn't empty, reallocate room for one more user
                else
                {
                    **this is the line in which the error occurs (second time reallocating,
                   third dynamic allocation total for this pointer)**
                head = (User *)realloc(head, (*menArraySize + 1) * sizeof(User));
                }
                //if the allocation failed
                if (head == NULL)
                    exit(1);
                //pointing to the new user we created
                head = &head[*menArraySize];
                //apply all details to the user
                strcpy(head->id, id);
                head->firstName = firstName;
                head->lastName = lastName;
                strcpy(head->age, age);
                head->gender = gender;
                head->userName = userName;
                head->password = password;
                head->hobbies = hobbies;
                head->description = description;
                //applying an index number to the user
                head->index = *menArraySize;
                //pointing back to the head of the array
                head = &head[0];
                //updating the variable showing the size of the array
                *menArraySize = *menArraySize + 1;
                return head;
            }
```

why is that happening? what can I do to fix it? thank you!

Comment: `head = &head[0];` does nothing. You have lost `head` when you did `head = &head[*menArraySize];`. Use another variable

Comment: Assignment similar to [Scanning data from text file, that doesn't have spacing between each item of data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53937287/2410359)

Comment: Notwithstanding the technical issues -- great job with the question Title... After making the suggested changes, you will never see the allocation of `head` in `main()` as `readInputFile` receives a copy of `head` and any allocations made outside of `main()` are lost (and a memory leak). Instead you need to pass the ***address of*** `head` (e.g. `&head`) and your parameter needs to be `User **head`.

Comment: As a general note about `addMale` -- if you are passing more than 4 parameters -- you should consider refactoring your code.

Comment: Even after fixes, you're not using `realloc` properly - you need to save the pointer to a temporary, then check, and only then assign the value from the temporary into your `head`. The `if` can be removed by setting the pointer to NULL if no array has been allocated - `realloc` will handle it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here:

```
head = &head[*menArraySize];
```

you're pointing on the new location, but you also overwrite (and lose) `head` original value (unless you substract). When you do:

```
head = &head[0];
```

you *think* you're restoring the original value, but that accomplishes nothing. You just reference/dereference the same value.

Solution: use another `User *temp` value to reference the new location. And keep `head` unchanged after you used `realloc`.

Comment: That was the perfect answer. I really appreciate it, thank you! (problem solved)

Comment: I'm glad, because there could have been some other issues :)

Comment: May I ask what problems? just out of curiosity

Comment: In `main()` after `readInputFile(head, &menArraySize, list);` -- do you still expect `head == NULL`? (better check) See my comments below the original question.

Answer (score 0):

[@Jean-François has covered the immediate bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53973176/14660). But a lot of trouble could be avoided by chopping the problem into better defined pieces.

What the code is doing is...

1. Open a file AND read from a file into a bunch of variables AND call another function to turn those variables into a User AND add it to a list.
2. Construct a User from a bunch of variables AND push it onto an array.

When you describe a function "and" is a hint it can be broken down into smaller functions. Pass through variables (`head`, `menArraySize`) indicate two separate actions have been unnecessarily wielded together. Finally needing to pass around paired variables (`head` and `menArraySize`) indicates maybe they should be turned into a struct.

Instead it should be separated like so...

1. Open a file.
2. Read a User from a file.
3. Push a User onto an array.

This results in two simpler functions with more well defined functionality.

```
User *UserRead(FILE *fp);
void UsersPush(Users *users, User *user);
```

And used like so.

```
FILE *input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
if( input == NULL ) {
    perror("Could not open input.txt");
    exit(1);
}

Users *users = UsersNew();

User *user = UserRead(input);
if( user == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not read user.\n");
    exit(1);
}
UsersPush(users, user);
```

Note that I've also made a Users struct to encapsulate the array, its size, and how many users are in it. This lets us pass around just one thing, a Users struct, and we can bite off just the work of dealing with the array.

```
typedef struct {
    // How many users?
    size_t num;
    // How much space do we have?
    size_t size;
    User **users;
} Users;

// Allocate and initialize Users.
Users *UsersNew() {
    Users *users = malloc(sizeof(Users));

    // Because we're storing the size separate from the number of users
    // we can preallocate some space. This makes the code simpler, no NULL
    // condition to worry about, and we can be smarter about growing the array.
    users->num = 0;
    users->size = 1;
    users->users = malloc(sizeof(Users*));

    return users;
}

// Isolate the tricky work of growing the array in its own function.
// This makes it reusable, and we can improve the growth algorithm.
void UsersGrowIfNecessary(Users *users) {
    // asserts like these to check for impossible conditions will save you
    // a lot of debugging time. This makes sure there's never more Users than
    // space for them.
    assert(users->size >= users->num );

    // Check if we need more space.
    if( users->size == users->num ) {
        // Double the size to avoid excessive expensive reallocs.
        size_t new_size = users->size * 2;
        users->users = realloc(users->users, sizeof(Users*) * new_size);
        users->size = new_size;
    }
}

// Add the user, growing the array if necessary.
void UsersPush(Users *users, User *user) {
    UsersGrowIfNecessary(users);

    // With all that done, adding the user is simple.
    users->users[users->num] = user;
    users->num++;
}
```

This can all be replaced with a generic self-growing array which stores `void *`. It's nice to implement it yourself for learning purposes, but for any serious code grab an existing implementation. I like [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Pointer-Arrays.html) because it's generic, well documented, well tested, and has many, many more features.

With that all taken care of, the work of allocating and reading a User can be tackled on its own.

```
typedef struct {
    char id[10];
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    int age;
    char gender;
    // etc...
} User;

User *UserNew() {
    // Use calloc to begin with everything zeroed.
    User *user = calloc(sizeof(User), 1);

    // 0 isn't always NULL.    
    user->firstName = NULL;
    user->lastName = NULL;

    return user;
}

User *UserRead(FILE *input) {
    User *user = UserNew();

    // The rest is left as an exercise.
    if( fscanf(input, "%9s", user->id) != 1 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't read user ID.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return user;
}
```